# Swing Explorer plugin for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-indigo

I manage to run Swing Explorer stand alone, but would really like to run an Eclipse plugin for it. From what i gather there is a plugin supporting Eclipse 3.2/3.4, but i can't get it to work in Indigo or find a newer plugin for Indigo. Has anyone managed to get it to work or know of a plugin for Indigo? If not, another plugin with the same functionality can be considered.

I have seen mention of JDeveloper having some similar functionality, but that is not a viable option for now, as we are Eclipse based.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: Depending on how it goes, you might also want to check out WindowBuilder.  It's WindowBuilder from Instantiations, bought out by Google and then Open Sourced at the Eclipse Foundation: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'll have a look even if i succeed with SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also use SwingExplorer extensively for debugging, but not the plugin itself. Take a look at how I manage it's launch configuration.

Main-Class

- `org.swingexplorer.Launcher`

Program Arguments:

- `org.yourcompany.YourMain`

To JVM Arguments I added

- `-javaagent:swag.jar`
- `-Xbootclasspath/a:swag.jar`
- `-Dswex.mport=63812`
- `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`

In Classpath

- 1 new Entry: `swexpl.jar` (contains `org.swingexplorer.Launcher`)

The nice thing about this approach is that it doesn't require SwingExplorer plugin, only the jars. You have pretty much functional SwingExplorer with only one feature missing, namely the Jump-to-code in Eclipse, when you click on any trace.

Sidenote: I also use Groovy Console in background wso that I can always easily alter any compoent I want (I wrote a function - inspired by JQuery's selector - to traverse Swing hierarchy). If you're interested I can also write about it in more detail.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it as soon as possible. Struggling with some ssl/MD5 troubles for the moment that need to get sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it in Indigo.

You can get the jar file [here](http://www.swingexplorer.com/?page=download).

Just click on the link *swexpl-eclipse.zip*. you have to enter an email and they'll send you the download link. I haven't found another way, but didn't get any newsletters or something like that by now.

then just follow the install instructions which can also be found on that page. nothing to complicated

Comment: I have the different files, but didn't manage to get it working that way.

Comment: I tried it again on a personal machine and there i was able to load the plugin. Not sure what the difference is between the machines.

Comment: The link on this site has been typo-squatted and doesn't look like anything related